# Como enviar e receber um arquivo via Socket?

Tags: c++, socket

Estou precisando enviar arquivos via Socket em C++ Linux, como o arquivo pode ter um conteúdo extenso será necessário envia-lo em pedaços. Neste caso, preciso criar uma especie de protocolo para enviar um arquivo (em pedaços) através do Sockets e poder juntar novamente no lado servidor e/ou no lado cliente. Será que alguém pode ajudar em como realizar esta tarefa, segue abaixo os métodos do Servidor e Cliente, respectivamente, onde consigo enviar e receber mensagens de texto entre o cliente e o servidor e vice versa.

```
// Método no Servidor, recebe e envia mensagem ao cliente.
void SocketServer::receiver()
{
   int read_size = -1;
   char msg_buf_recv[MAX_MSG];
   char msg_buf_send[MAX_MSG];
   std::string client_message;

   while( (read_size = ::recv(sockClient, msg_buf_recv, sizeof(msg_buf_recv), 0)) > 0)
   {
       std::cout << msg_buf_recv << std::endl;
       std::cout << "Servidor: ";
       std::cin.getline(msg_buf_send, sizeof(msg_buf_send));

       write(sockClient, msg_buf_send, sizeof(msg_buf_send));
   }

   if(read_size == 0)
   {
       std::cout << "\nClient disconnected" << std::endl;
   }
   else if(read_size == -1)
   {
       std::cerr << "Recv failed" << std::endl;
   }
}
```

```
// Método cliente enviar e recebe mensagens ao servidor.
bool SocketClient::conectar() 
{
    char server_message[MAX_MSG];
    char client_message[MAX_MSG];

    if ( connect(sockClient, (struct sockaddr *)&client , sizeof(client)) < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Connect failed. Error" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "Connectando..." << std::endl;
    sleep( 1 );
    system("clear");
    std::cout << "Conectado ao Servidor IP: " << ipClient << std::endl;

    while(1)
    {
        std::cout << "Marcos: ";
        std::cin.getline (client_message, sizeof(client_message));

        //Send some data
        if( send(sockClient, client_message, sizeof(client_message), 0) < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Send failed" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        std::cout << "Client message: " << client_message << std::endl;

        //Receive a reply from the server
        if( recv(sockClient, server_message, sizeof(server_message), 0) < 0)
        {
           std::cerr << "recv failed" << std::endl;
           return false;
        }
        std::cout << "Server message: " << server_message << std::endl;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Nessa explicação não vou me aprofundar em exemplos de "manual mapping" ou em como tratar arquivos diferentes, pois não há a necessidade, já que estamos apenas transferindo dados hexadecimais.

## Formatação do cabeçalho

Pegue as informações que você julga necessarias como: tamanho, nome, formato (pode já estar inclusa no nome)... Neste caso vou mostrar como pegar o tamanho do arquivo.

```
ifstream file( "example.txt", ios::binary | ios::ate);
return file.tellg();
```

Lembrando que na operação acima o arquivo ainda não foi alocado em seu programa, estamos simplesmente lendo a metadata do mesmo, você pode pegar informações do arquivo diretamente pela GetFileAttributes ou GetFileAttributesEx.

Você pode enviar um cabeçalho no formato file name + file size + [md5 hash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382380(v=vs.85).aspx) que já é o suficiente para garantir que o documento seja enviado e validado.

## Enviando o arquivo

Vou fazer um exemplo mostrando o envio de um documento pequeno, que não tenha a necessidade de manipular a memoria do seu programa de forma inteligente para evitar o consumo excessivo de RAM.

### Alocando o arquivo em seu programa

Primeiramente você deve abrir ele e transforma-lo em um byte array

```
static std::vector<char> ReadAllBytes(char const* filename)
{
    ifstream ifs(filename, ios::binary|ios::ate);
    ifstream::pos_type pos = ifs.tellg();

    std::vector<char>  result(pos);

    ifs.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    ifs.read(&result[0], pos);

    return result;
}
```

Se você estiver preocupado com a eficiencia do codigo passe o resultado como parametro:

```
static void ReadAllBytes(char const* filename, std::vector<char>& result)
```

E se o documento for muito grande (maior de 1mb) utilize malloc() antes de começar a alocar os bytes (isso serve para o recebimento também)

Depois quebra-lo em "pedaços" (ou pacotes) de 32 bytes cada. Mas isso vamos fazer no próximo passo.

### Loop de envio

Aproveitando um pouco do seu código...

```
std::vector<char> rts;
int pos = 0;
ReadAllBytes("arquivo.txt", rts);

while(filesize > pos*32)
{
    if( send(sockClient, rts[pos * 32], 32, 0) < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Send failed" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Loop de recebimento

```
char (*rec);
rec = malloc(filesize);
int bytesRecv = 0;

while(bytesRecv*32 < filesize)
{
    if(recv(sockClient,rec[bytesRecv*32],32,0))
    {
        bytesRecv++;
    }
}
```

Então salve em um arquivo

```
FILE* file = fopen( filename, "wb" );
fwrite( rec , 1, filesize, file );
```

[Source](https://github.com/VitorCaleffi/Socket-file-send/)

Comment: Dica muito boa e utilizei em minha aplicação, porém, ainda estou com dúvida para o recebimento do arquivo do lado Servidor/Cliente, ou seja, o recv, como faço para juntar as partes?

Comment: @Marcos desculpe a demora, estava longe do computador, fiz meio de cabeça pois estou sem nenhum compilador a vista. Vou tentar atualizar novamente amanha com um source completo.

Comment: obrigado, fico aguardando o source completo, como não consegui entender direito, acabei tentando refazer tudo, mas não está dando certo. Se tiver tudo completo o entendimento ficará bem melhor e será de grande ajuda.

Comment: @Marcos https://www.dropbox.com/s/k08u4ya6k0babj2/Server.rar?dl=0

Comment: Obrigado pela força Vitor! Vou analisar para entender melhor essa matéria.

Answer (score 2):

Alguns métodos que uso para envio de arquivo usando fstream e FILE.
eu comentei algumas coisas, espero que ajude.

Leitura de arquivos, e envio para o cliente.

```
void Socket_Manip::FILE_SEND(char directory[]) {

    std::ifstream::pos_type size;
    char* memblock;

    std::ifstream file(directory, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate);

    if (file.is_open()) {
    size = file.tellg(); // recebendo o tamanho do arquivo atraves da função tellg

        //envio do tamanho do arquivo para o endereço remoto.
        char GotFileSize[1024];
        snprintf(GotFileSize, 1024, "%d", size); //concatenando em GotFileSIze o inteiro de Size
        send(new_sockfd, GotFileSize, 1024, 0); // enviando para o socket o tamanho do arquivo
        if(size > 0) {
            memblock = new char[size]; // alocação com o tamanho do arquivo.
            file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg); // posicionando o ponteiro no inicio do arquivo.
            file.read(memblock, size); // leitura do arquivo
            file.close(); // fechando o arquivo.
            send(new_sockfd, memblock, size, 0); // enviando para o socket o conteudo.

            delete[] memblock;
            }
    }
    Close_Socket(); // função para encerrar a conexão
}
```

Receber Arquivos do servidor:

```
void Socket_Manip::FILE_READ(char directory[]) {
    //File Size
    recv(sockfd, GotFileSize, MY_BUFFER_SIZE, 0); // recebe o tamanho do arquivo

    long FileSize = atoi(GotFileSize); // converte o tamanho do arquivo para inteiro
    long SizeCheck = 0; //variavel auxiliar para o loop
    FILE *fp = fopen("/home/rh4yd3n/Downloads/file.zip", "w"); //abrindo o arquivo para escrita
    char* mfcc;  // variavel onde você irá alocar o tamanho dinamicamente.
    if(FileSize > 1499) {
        mfcc = (char*)malloc(1500); // alocação na variavel 
        while(SizeCheck < FileSize){
            int Received = recv(sockfd, mfcc, 1500, 0);
            SizeCheck += Received;
            fwrite(mfcc, 1, Received, fp);
            fflush(fp);
            printf("Filesize: %d\nSizecheck: %d\nReceived: %d\n\n", FileSize, SizeCheck, Received);
        }
    } else { 
        mfcc = (char*)malloc(FileSize + 1);
        int Received = recv(sockfd, mfcc, FileSize, 0);
        fwrite(mfcc, 1, Received, fp);
        fflush(fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    close(sockfd);
    free(mfcc);
    return 0;
}
```